# Как удалить временные архивы, скачанные pip?

Tags: python

Работаю в Ubuntu 14. Пытался поставить matplotlib командой типа pip install matplotlib, он не смог скомпилиться (логично, я потом выяснил что этот pip идёт к python 2.7, а для python3 нужен pip3). При установке pip скачивал архив, из которого потом распаковывал matplotlib, и я не уверен удаляет ли он этот временный архив после распаковки. В хелп лазил, чего-то полезного не нашёл. **Можно ли заставить pip удалить скачанные им временные файлы?**

Comment: для справки: есть [дистрибутивный пакет](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/python-matplotlib), который, конечно, использовать предпочтительней.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

в pip, насколько я знаю, нет такой функции.
Это можно сделать так:

1. Удалите папку .pip/cache
2. Вы можете проигнорировать установленные пакеты - --ignore-installed
3. В последних версиях pip (c 6, по-моему) есть опция --no-cache-dir